# XSLT template conditional statement on lookup fields - Optimization help

Tags: 2010, xslt, optimization

I have a block of xslt that examines if the current node and performs some calculations using different lookup fields if a certain field matches a certain text string. It works as expected and is reasonably fast. I am fairly new to XSLT and would like to optimize this template as much as possible, hopefully so its only a few lines and not the same block repeating over and over with only the variable being different. Example of the code:

```
<td class="jobRow centerCell" colspan="1">
                <xsl:if test="$fieldvalue = 'RN'">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x007 = ''">
                            <span>0</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span style="font-size:8px;color:red">No budget assigned!</span>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <span style="padding-left:20px;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x007,'0.0')"/>
                            </span>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$fieldvalue = 'ADM SEC'">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x001 = ''">
                            <span>0</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span style="font-size:8px;color:red">No budget assigned!</span>
                            <xsl:variable name="JobBudget">0</xsl:variable>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <span style="padding-left:20px;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x001,'0.0')"/>
                            </span>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$fieldvalue = 'CHG RN'">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x002 = ''">
                            <span>0</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span style="font-size:8px;color:red">No budget assigned!</span>
                            <xsl:variable name="JobBudget">0</xsl:variable>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <span style="padding-left:20px;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x002,'0.0')"/>
                            </span>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$fieldvalue = 'PCA'">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x005 = ''">
                            <span>0</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span style="font-size:8px;color:red">No budget assigned!</span>
                            <xsl:variable name="JobBudget">0</xsl:variable>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <span style="padding-left:20px;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x005,'0.0')"/>
                            </span>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
```

As you can see, the action occurs within a table cell and first tests if the text is a match, and when it is performs a calculation. The only difference between each calculation is the lookup field reference.

I am working on some experimentation and will post with anything I come up. Any help or direction is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly noticed at least the repeating block could be refactored.

For example, declare the following Xsl template for rendering Budget:

```
<xsl:template name="RenderBudget">
    <xsl:param name="CostCenter"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$CostCenter = ''">
            <span>0</span>
            <br/>
            <span style="font-size:8px;color:red">No budget assigned!</span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span style="padding-left:20px;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">
             <xsl:value-of select="format-number($CostCenter,'0.0')"/>
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

and then invoke it

```
<xsl:call-template name="RenderBudget">
    <xsl:with-param name="CostCenter" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Job_x0020_Title = $fieldvalue and substring-after(@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center.,'#') = $jobvalue]/@Test_x0020_Cost_x0020_Center_x002"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

> Note:the code has not been tested